# Php Content insert page not working

Tags: php, file-upload, boolean, content-management-system

I'v been trying to make a content insert page with php and here is my code

```
    <?php // Initialize variables to null.
$title =""; // Sender Name
$author =''; // Sender's email ID
$date =date('d-m-y'); // Subject of mail
$desc="";//meta description
$keywords="";//meta keywords
$content =""; // Sender's Message
$category="";//chosen category
$pattern1="";//preg_match pattern
$nameError ="";
$contentError ="";
$purposeError ="";
$messageError ="";
$successMessage =""; // On submittingform below function will execute.
$img_dir=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/practise/grafitti/images/';
$img;


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Checking null values in message.
        //check and assign title title
        if(empty($_POST["title_post"])){
            $nameError = "A title is required";
             errors($nameError);
             exit();

        }
        else{
         if (preg_match("/^(\w|\s)$/",$_POST['title_post']))
        {
            $titleError = "Only letters,numbers and white space allowed";
            errors($titleError);

        }else{
          $title=$_POST['title_post'];
        }
        }


       // Checking null values inthe content.
        if (empty($_POST["content_post"]))
        {
            $contentError = "You have not posted any content.<br/> Please do to proceed";
            errors($contentError);
            exit();
        }else {
          $content=$_POST["content_post"];
        }

        //check and assign category
        if(!empty($_POST["categories_post"]))
         {
            $category=$_POST["categories_post"];
        }

        //Chexk and assign authors name
        if (!empty($_POST["author_post"]))
        {
        $author=$_POST["author_post"];
        }

        //check and assign value of description
        if (!empty($_POST["desc_post"]))
        {
        $desc=$_POST["desc_post"];
        }

        //check and assign keywords
        if (!empty($_POST["keywords_post"]))
        {
        $keywords=$_POST["keywords_post"];
        }

        //process images
        if(isset($_FILES["img_post"])){
          echo "good to go";
               $name=$_FILES["img_post"]["name"];
               $tmp_name=$_FILES["img_post"]["tmp_name"];
               $type=$_FILES["img_post"]["type"];
               $size=$_FILES["img_post"]["size"];
               $img_dir;

            if(upload($name,$type,$size,$tmp_name,$img_dir)){
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$img_dir.$name)){
                    echo "success";
                }else{echo php_info;}

                $img_upload_Success="File was uploaded successfully";
               errors($img_upload_Success);

            }else{
               $img_upload_Error="File could not be uploaded";
               errors($img_upload_Error);
               exit();
            }
        }

         echo $title."<br/>";
         echo $author."<br/>";
         echo $desc."<br/>";
         echo $keywords."<br/>";
         echo $category."<br/>";
         echo $date."<br/>";
}

      // Function for filtering input values.function test_input($data)


         function errors($err){
        echo "<script>
         var err='$err'
        alert(err)
         </script>
          ";
         }

  #validate file upload
  function upload($fl_name,$fl_type,$fl_size,$fl_tmp_name,$dir){
     #check to see if the file is an image or not
      if($fl_type!="image/jpeg" && $fl_type!="image/png" && $fl_type!="image/jpg" && $fl_type!="image/gif"){
        $typeError="The file type you uploaded is not supported";
        errors($fl_type);
        exit();
        }

      #check file size limits
      if($fl_size>512000){
        $sizeError="Size of the file is too big. Should be at least 500KB";
        errors($sizeError);
        exit();
       }

      if(file_exists($dir.$fl_name)){
        $existError="Sorry. File already exists";
        errors($existError);
        exit();
      }
  }
?>
```

the problem is,when  I want to validate with the file upload. If I don't upload anything the the code still assumes that my ***$_FILES['img_post']*** isset and it therefore runs the code that satisfies that conditions.
Moreover, if I manage to set the ***$_FILE***  variable, it still won't upload.Its like the

```
if(upload($name,$type,$size,$tmp_name,$img_dir))
```

returns a false value but the **upload()** is executed.Can someone please tell me how to handle the isset problem and at least a way to show the error causing the file not to be uploaded

Comment: Just check `$_FILES["img_post"]["tmp_name"] != ""` with your `isset($_FILES["img_post"])`. So it will become `if(isset($_FILES["img_post"]) && $_FILES["img_post"]["tmp_name"] != ""){`.

Comment: Hello,  you can check whether the name or tmp_name is set for the file component .. _FILES["img_post"]["tmp_name"]  or _FILES["img_post"]["name"] . In case , to check whether upload success or not, _FILES["img_post"]["error"] will return the status, =0 means success

Comment: the `$_FILE["img_post"]`all worked but still the file won't upload. I think the problem could be the `upload()` since `if(upload($name,$type,$size,$tmp_name,$img_dir))` returns a false result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

```
  if($_FILES['img_post']['error']==0) { 
  // process 
} else { 
  $error_message = $error_types[$_FILES['img_post']['error']]; 
  // do whatever with the error message 
}
```

For more details you can refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition below:

```
if($_FILES['img_post']['error'] == 0){
   //uplode file
}
```

This will check is it's empty or file been selected. If selected, then it will only upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
if(isset($_FILES["img_post"])){
```

to

```
if(isset($_FILES["img_post"]["tmp_name"])){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
if(isset($_FILES["img_post"]["tmp_name"]) && $_FILES["img_post"]["tmp_name"] != ''){
   //uplode file
}
```

OR

```
if(!empty($_FILES["img_post"]["tmp_name"])){
   //uplode file
}
```